# Any hidden problems exists if i set CHECK_POLICY = OFF

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a Store procedure to create auto generate SQl users.

code to create  User

```
CREATE  LOGIN  userName with PASSWORD= 'autoGeneratedPass'
```

**Problem**:  When the auto generated Password is weak then i got the below error

```
 Password validation failed. The password does not meet Windows policy requirements   because it is too short.
```

so i turned off  Windows policy checking

Code

```
CREATE  LOGIN  userName with PASSWORD= 'autoGeneratedPass' CHECK_POLICY = OFF
```

**If i did that any hidden problem arise?**

Comment: Would it not be better, overall, to generate stronger passwords?

Comment: iam creating a strong random password but because it is random i can't trust that, so any suggestions?

Comment: Catch the failure, run you random generator again, repeat until it succeeds?